# can not connect to itune store while click on rating within application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipad-mini, appirater

I would like to open app link in iTunes, while click on "rate this app" link.
But issue is that

> **"can not proceed your request" or "can not connect to itune store".**

It only happens in iPad mini. Otherwise works fine.
Please anybody can solve this issue.

```
+ (void)rateApp {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSLog(@"APPIRATER NOTE: iTunes App Store is not supported on the iOS simulator. Unable to open App Store page.");   
#else
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // added work arround for wrong URL Scheme used in new App store on iOS 6
    NSString *reviewURL;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0) {
        reviewURL = [templateReviewURLiOS6 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"APP_ID" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", APPIRATER_APP_ID]];

        reviewURL = [reviewURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"LANGUAGE" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]];
        NSLog(@"reviewURL: %@",reviewURL);

    } else {
        reviewURL = [templateReviewURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"APP_ID" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", APPIRATER_APP_ID]];
    }

    [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:kAppiraterRatedCurrentVersion];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reviewURL]];
#endif
}
```

Comment: Try to log your reviewURL before openURL method and check you get the valid URL from the code.

Comment: I hope your iPad mini is having iOS 6. What kind of other devices you have tried? What are their iOS versions? If they are below iOS 6, then there is an issue with your code in `IF` loop. I saw your iTunes link. It looks weird bcoz of some prefix in it.

Comment: Hey Bro This is not my code for rate this is from iRate Repo and its work fine with other all device have iOS 6.o

Comment: finally i got solution, just replace your latest iRate repo lib and it'll work fine...